# How do I provide Team City with a file?

Tags: build-process, build-automation, teamcity

We are looking at modifying our build process so that our configuration files are all template based.  We will then have a local.properties.xml file which will be used by NAnt to create configuration files that are specific to the person running the build.

My question is how can I safely provide TeamCity with a file considering we don't want to check in the local.properties.xml?  I'm pretty sure that TeamCity nukes the build directory it has so I don't think I can just drop a file in their.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see the hackish way only: post your file as an artifact of some build and retrieve it with help of [artifact dependencies](http://www.jetbrains.net/confluence/display/TCD4/5.Dependencies#5.Dependencies-uiDependencyByArtifact).

Comment: In the end I actually figured out how to use Team City properties to supply parameters to my build file but this is the only way I could figure out of doing it via file as well...